# Tell LabelEnocder to ignore new labels?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, encoder

I'm working with text data where a lot of user error has to be accounted for, eg. there are a lot of cases where upon predicting new data, new labels will occur that the encoder hasn't seen before due to typos etc. I just want to ignore these (so when I run `labelencoder.transform(df_newdata['GL_Description'])`, I just want it to ignore anything it hasn't seen before). How can I do this? I didn't find a parameter for this in the docs, but is the only way really to check every word one-by-one "by hand" and drop them? Is there a way I can tell the encoder to ignore any new labels that are not in its dictionary?

Comment: It will do that automatically. No need to do anything. It will ignore words not already present in vocabulary. But make sure not to call `fit()` or `fit_transform()` again. Only call `transform()`

Comment: But it doesn't! I get a `y contains new labels` error.

Comment: @VivekKumar oh right, my bad... TF-IDF didn't throw the error, LabelEncoder did. I've updated the question.

Comment: Are you using that on targets or features? How do you want to deal with it? I mean how will you fill the value ignored? Some random value. Please explain in more detail.

Comment: I'm using it on features. I'd be happy if I could mark these categoricals as "unknown", just to make the code run/predict. Then I can add the new data back to the original dataset and train again every now and then. I just want to make sure the code doesn't crash when encountering new input.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you can override the original LabelEncoder with a custom encoder. 
Something like this:

```
import numpy as np
class TolerantLabelEncoder(LabelEncoder):
    def __init__(self, ignore_unknown=False,
                       unknown_original_value='unknown', 
                       unknown_encoded_value=-1):
        self.ignore_unknown = ignore_unknown
        self.unknown_original_value = unknown_original_value
        self.unknown_encoded_value = unknown_encoded_value

    def transform(self, y):
        check_is_fitted(self, 'classes_')
        y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

        indices = np.isin(y, self.classes_)
        if not self.ignore_unknown and not np.all(indices):
            raise ValueError("y contains new labels: %s" 
                                         % str(np.setdiff1d(y, self.classes_)))

        y_transformed = np.searchsorted(self.classes_, y)
        y_transformed[~indices]=self.unknown_encoded_value
        return y_transformed

    def inverse_transform(self, y):
        check_is_fitted(self, 'classes_')

        labels = np.arange(len(self.classes_))
        indices = np.isin(y, labels)
        if not self.ignore_unknown and not np.all(indices):
            raise ValueError("y contains new labels: %s" 
                                         % str(np.setdiff1d(y, self.classes_)))

        y_transformed = np.asarray(self.classes_[y], dtype=object)
        y_transformed[~indices]=self.unknown_original_value
        return y_transformed
```

Example Usage:

```
en = TolerantLabelEncoder(ignore_unknown=True)
en.fit(['a','b'])

print(en.transform(['a', 'c', 'b']))
# Output: [ 0 -1  1]

print(en.inverse_transform([-1, 0, 1]))
# Output: ['unknown' 'a' 'b']
```

Comment: what should be check_is_fitted?

Comment: @MT467 `check_is_fitted` is internal scikit method. See this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.validation.check_is_fitted.html

Comment: Upvote - you need to add this though at your code: `from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted, column_or_1d`, right?

Comment: By the way, also I am not sure how good the wording is `ignore_unknown=True` - in this case you actually take into account the unknowns and you even encode them so not ignoring them at all (!!). Ignore would be something like to skip them and neither throw an error on them as the original `LabelEncoder` does nor to encode them.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare an unknown class('*UNK*') for each string columnscloumns

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(preprocessing.LabelEncoder)
df.select_dtypes(include='object').append({}.fromkeys(df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns, '_UNK_'), ignore_index=True).apply(lambda x: d[x.name].fit_transform(x))
```

Unseen column values can be classified as unknown class

```
dftc = dfTest.select_dtypes(include='object').apply(lambda x: d[x.name].transform(list(map(lambda xx: xx if xx in d[x.name].classes_ else '_UNK_', x))))
```