# How to use Pandas get_dummies on predict data?

Tags: one-hot-encoding

After using Pandas `get_dummies` on 3 categorical columns to get a one hot-encoded Dataframe, I've trained (with some success) a Perceptron model.

Now I would like to predict the result from a new observation, that it is not hot-encoded.

Is there any way to record the `get_dummies` column mapping to re-use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no automatic procedure to do it at the moment, to my knowledge. In the future release of `sklearn` `CategoricalEncoder` will be very handy for this job. You can already get your hands on it, if you clone `sklearn` github master branch and build in yourself. At the moment 2 options come to my mind:

- use `LabelEncoder+OneHotEncoder` combination, see [this answer, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50443410/9640384);
- simply retrieve (and store, if needed) the list of columns after the training OHE output. Then run `pd.get_dummies` on the test set/example. Loop through the output test OHE columns, drop those that do not appear in the training OHE and add those that are missing in test OHE filled with zeros.

Comment: I was thinking of doing the second one.  That will work, but I thought this could not possibly be the expected way since any process that creates features for training (such as One Hot Encoding) must also "work" for prediction for a model to be worth anything,

Comment: You are right, but sadly i'm not aware of the "proper" implementation. If you find it in an open-source package, do not hesitate to share

Comment: @demongolem Did you manage to find anything better? I think the first is actually the "correct" solution, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62241515/12162243) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63432953/12162243). On the first link there's the 2nd solution also described using [pandas reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html). And here's [one more example for using reindex](https://predictivehacks.com/?all-tips=how-to-deal-with-get_dummies-in-train-and-test-dataset)