# how to predict values given that you have multiple dummy columns?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a data frame that looks similar to:

```
   salary   job title  Raiting   Company_Name  Location   Seniority  
0  100         SE         5          apple        sf          vp
1  120         DS         4         Samsung       la          Jr
2  230         QA         5         google        sd          Sr
```

(My `df` has more categorical features than this)

Usually, when predicting from a model it goes something like

```
in[1]: inModel_name.predict(catagory_1, catagory_2,..etc)
out[2]: predicted_var
```

Whereas after you use `pd.get_dummies` you have a drastic amount more of columns depending on how many categorical features you have made, making the method I mentioned before impractical when trying to predict data. How do you go about referencing the multiple columns instead of manually putting in 0s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `pd.get_dummies` I would recommend using [sklearn's onehotencoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)

Check this [link](https://stackabuse.com/one-hot-encoding-in-python-with-pandas-and-scikit-learn/) for details on how to replace pd.get_dummies with proper data encoding methods.

This allows you to use `.fit_transform` on your training data to get one hot encoded representation for training. And when trying to use test data for prediction you can simply just use its `.transform` method to get one hot encoded representation for those as well.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
X = [['Male', 1], ['Female', 3], ['Female', 2]]
enc.fit(X)
enc.categories_
```

```
[array(['Female', 'Male'], dtype=object), array([1, 2, 3], dtype=object)]
```

```
enc.transform([['Female', 1], ['Male', 4]]).toarray()
```

```
array([[1., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```